# ADO Recordset on Excel Data Range

Tags: excel, ado, recordset, vba

I created an ADO recordset on an Excel named range that contains a time series of value. The columns of the series has dates for the field names. Trying to locate the first dated column but having trouble. The name property for any of the date named fields returns what looks like a field index (e.g. "F36") rather than the actual date. 2 questions, 1) how can I return the index of a specific field; 2) why is the name of the date field converted to a field index. Sorry if the answers are obvious but I'm a little stuck. Thanks.

Comment: Are all of your non-date fields picking up that `f<ordinal>` type of name as well? It sounds like perhaps your header row isn't being treated as one.

Comment: JNevill... Thx for responding. No the other field names are returned as they are shown in the source range. I could use the index of a non-date field to offset to the date fields but I'm having trouble returning the index/ordinal of those fields.